# Declarações if/else e time.sleep()

Tags: python

Estou com uma dúvida. É possível colocar o `time.sleep()` numa declaração `if/else`?

Exemplo:

```
import time
if time.sleep(2):
    print "hello"
else:
    #alguma coisa
```

Procurei na internet mas não encontrei resultados esclarecedores.

Comment: Uma vez alguém responde, não é correto mudar a pergunta. Por favor, abra uma nova pergunta e faça referência à esta.

Comment: Como faço essa referência?

Comment: É só linkar "na minha [pergunta anterior](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23823) etc etc..."

Comment: [Esta pergunta está sendo discutida no Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1682/o-que-fazer-quando-o-o-p-muda-sua-pergunta)

Answer (score 6):

Não, repare o que ocorre se executar o seguinte código:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import time

var = time.sleep(2)
print(var)
```

Saída:

> None

Logo, não se pode usar pois o método time.sleep() não retorna valor, o que poderia fazer (embora não faça sentido é) :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import time

var = time.sleep(2)
print(var)
if var is None:
  print("Verdadeiro")
else:
  #nunca entrará aqui
  print("falso")
```

Apesar de você ler, python 2.7, este código está compatível com a versão 3.

Comment: Então como posso fazer com que passados 2 segundos ele imprima algo? exemplo: if #passados 2 segundos: print "hello"

Comment: o `time.sleep(2)` já suspende a thread para você. Não precisa de colocar em uma operação condicional. É só colocar `time.sleep(2)` e `print("Olá mundo")`

Comment: elif machine == "":
            import time
            if temp >=20: 
                print "A iniciar o PowerBIT 1.0..."              
                starting_so = time.sleep(float(temp))